# Is there a human-readable summary of Apple's Terms and Conditions?

Tags: iphone, apple-store

Just went to update my apps on my iPhone and it looks like Apple have updated their **Terms and Conditions and Apple Privacy Policy**. It's currently at 62 pages!

Has anyone read it thoroughly and can give a **short** summary of any important items for users? I appreciate this won't be a legal answer (that'll also take 62 pages) but a general summary would be handy, e.g. am I promising to go on their mailing list or something like that?

**Clarification:** the best answer won't be legally accurate (because only the T&C themselves are) but it will state if there are any gotchas or weird stuff users should be aware of.

Comment: This is a legal document - so any short summary is worthless

Comment: Do you really need a summary of the entire document, or just particular areas?

Comment: @PhilipRegan: just the bits that will really affect me as a user. I appreciate that is somewhat subjective, but there must be a few highlights.

Comment: Of course, a legal and correct answer requires advise from a lawyer.  However I would still be interested in an non-legally-binding possibly-inaccurate summary letting me know if they snuck-in a requirement to give up my first-borne child, or some such.

Comment: @hotpaw2: exactly! That is **exactly** what I'm trying to find out: not a legally binding precise answer but *"is there a weird stuff?"*

Comment: There was a very good article on CNN: "[What you should know about iTunes' 56-page legal terms](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/TECH/web/05/06/itunes.terms/index.html)". It is little bit outdated, but still interesting.

Comment: @dmirkitanov: excellent link with a great summary; this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has on their website the latest versions all of their legal documents on their website: http://www.apple.com/legal/. Some of those pages offer summaries of the policies, but not many of them have that.

At the same time @Mark makes a valid point: there is a reason why these legal documents are so long. If you want a summary, then it would be best to have a lawyer look it over and give you the information you need. I think any take away from their documentation is that Apple is very restrictive when it comes to their branding, content, technologies, processes, and the like.